# android to how start a new fragment on Menu click

Tags: android

In android, how to have menu onClick start new fragment? i'm creating Fragment inside tabLayout? How to set menu click start new fragment? See my code, how can I display a new fragment when clicked from menu items?

```
public class NetworkFragment extends Fragment {
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;

public NetworkFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
public static NetworkFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    NetworkFragment fragment = new NetworkFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_network, container, false);





    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)view. findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    final PagerAdapter pagerAdapter =
            new PagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), getContext());
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

    // Give the TabLayout the ViewPager
    final TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout)view. findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    // Iterate over all tabs and set the custom view
    for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
        TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(i);
        tab.setCustomView(pagerAdapter.getTabView(i));
    }


    final ImageView menuView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.menuView);
    menuView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getContext(), v);
            popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.network_menu, popup.getMenu());
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You Clicked : " + item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    if(item.getItemId() ==R.id.allLinks){
                        //new Fragment

                    }
                    else if(item.getItemId() ==R.id.networkFavourites){
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "networkFavourites" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else if(item.getItemId() ==R.id.CompanyLinks){
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "CompanyLinks" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else if(item.getItemId() ==R.id.Company){
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "CompanyLinks" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else if(item.getItemId() ==R.id.Industry){
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "CompanyLinks" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }


                    return true;
                }
            });
            popup.show();
        }
    });


    return view;
}

class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    String tabTitles[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.network_tab);
    Context context;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabTitles.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new MylinksFragment();
            case 1:
                return new MyGroupsFragment();
            case 2:
                return new MyInvitationsFragment();
            case 3:
                return new MyMessagesFragment();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // Generate title based on item position
        return tabTitles[position];
    }

    public View getTabView(int position) {
        View tab = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.tab_text_layout, null);
        TextView tv = (TextView) tab.findViewById(R.id.custom_text);
        tv.setText(tabTitles[position]);
        return tab;
    }

}
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Actually your question is not clear. But as per my understanding you want to display a new fragment on menu click. To do so you have to write a code like

for API level 2.2 and above and when you are using a v4 support jar

```
Fragment fragment = new YourFragmentName();// the fragment which you ant to display
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container,fragment).commit();
```

for API level 3.0 and above and when you are not using a v4 support jar

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
```

By this way you can replace a fragment or display a new fragment.

Comment: hey see above Images

Comment: so you want to show the mylink section on click of menu all links? If yes then you just need to use the viewpager.setCurrentItem() method in which you need to pass the position of the fragment which you ant to display in your case it will be viewpager.setCurrentItem(0)

Comment: toobbar and tablayout as it is  start fragment  as like open tab click

Comment: i have Menu  button i want to change my Fragment on click ?